# Load data into a new BigQuery Table with different partition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have been trying to load a BigQuery Dump from a daily partitioned table to an hourly partitioned table and I am facing the following error:
I created a new table partitioned hourly as we found that hourly partitioning performs better for our business model and I am now trying to migrate the data from the daily partitioned table to the hourly.

Both tables are partitioned on a column **dt** (timestamp) and the only difference is that the new table has a partitioning expiration of 180 days and few fields used to cluster the partitions by **cid**, **mt**, **clid**, **sid**. Both tables are under the same dataset in the same region. I exported the data in JSON format in a bucket and now I am trying to import it and I am getting this error:

```
 query: Too many partitions produced by query, allowed 4000, query
produces at least 4050 partitions
```

the command that I am using is the following:

```
bq load --project_id=<my-project-id> --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --noreplace --autodetect --time_partitioning_type=HOUR --time_partitioning_field=dt --time_partitioning_expiration=15552000 --clustering_fields=cid,mt,clid,sid --noreplace -ignore_unknown_values=true  <my-dataset>.<my-new-table> gs://<my-bucket>/<shards-name>*
```

In the command above, everything between angle brackets is replaced with my current project dataset, table, and bucket.
Is there any workaround to import the dump? One more info: The daily table has **624,892,214. rows**.
I also found in the GCP documentation that a table can only have 4000 tables which explains the error, but then how can I load the older data?

Thanks

Comment: You can't go above the 4000 partitions by table (even if the team is working on it). Therefore you need to create another table when you reach this limit. One current option is to use 1 table per quarter.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables) as a reference to what @[guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) has mentioned.

Consider exploring table [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#when_to_use_clustering) as this is a better option when dealing with more than 4000 partitions. Combining both [clustering and partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#combinine-clustered-partitioned-tables) is another viable option but will need a little bit more time and technical skills for a successful deployment.

There's also this guide that you can use for [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas#ts-number-column-partition-quota).